# Can I show the sql trasaction running status on the frontend

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

With `Sequelize` transaction, https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html,

```
try {

  const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    const user = await User.create({
      firstName: 'Abraham',
      lastName: 'Lincoln'
    }, { transaction: t });

    await user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, { transaction: t });

    return user;

  });

  // If the execution reaches this line, the transaction has been committed successfully
  // `result` is whatever was returned from the transaction callback (the `user`, in this case)

} catch (error) {

  // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
  // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

}
```

Is it possible I can display the transaction running status on the frontend? For example, before running `setShooter` and there is no error yet on `User.create`, on the frontend, I will display `creating a user` and after create user, I will display `setting shooter` on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
You will need to implement a loader on the client that will wait for the afterCommit call and display the message you want during the execution of your logic after the transactions.

A transaction object allows tracking if and when it is committed.

An afterCommit hook can be added to both managed and unmanaged transaction objects:

Managed transaction:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
  t.afterCommit(() => {
    // Your logic
  });
});
```

Unmanaged transaction:

```
const t = await sequelize.transaction();
t.afterCommit(() => {
  // Your logic
});
await t.commit();
```

The callback passed to afterCommit can be async. In this case:

The `sequelize.transaction` call will wait for it before settling;
The `t.commit` call will wait for it before settling.

The afterCommit hook is not raised if the transaction is rolled back;
The afterCommit hook does not modify the return value of the transaction
You can use the afterCommit hook in conjunction with model hooks to know when a instance is saved and available outside of a transaction

```
User.afterSave((instance, options) => {
  if (options.transaction) {
    // Save done within a transaction, wait until transaction is committed to
    // notify listeners the instance has been saved
    options.transaction.afterCommit(() => /* Notify */)
    return;
  }
  // Save done outside a transaction, safe for callers to fetch the updated model
  // Notify
});
```